# example.com/index.php/%postname is working while /%postname is not working Wordpress on IIS6

Tags: permalinks, iis

client had a WordPress install already running on IIS. when i am trying to change permalink, it is working only with /index.php/%postname. my site on **IIS6**

[image: Permalink Settings]

also created **web.config** file with below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

What I can't do:

- Upgrade to IIS7
- Switch to Apache
- Quit my job

Those suggestions have been offered to me, which sadly, I can't do any of those. Just an, FYI.

Much thanks for anyone who can lead me in the right direction.

Comment: This is an IIS question, therefor off-topic here

Comment: Try ISAP_Rewrite_Lite for II6 http://www.kylecaulfield.com/permalink-for-wordpress-iis-6-mod_rewrite-fixed-free

Comment: You might have more luck asking this question on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com) or [Pro Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com).